# Declaring <h:inputFile> as passthrough element

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2, passthrough-elements

I'm developing in JSF 2.2 using passthrough elements and I would like to translate `<h:inputFile>` into a passthrough element. I searched in the internet but didn't found any solution using passthrough elements.

Which HTML5 should I passthrough to render it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [jsf tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm)

```
<input type="file" jsf:id="myFile" jsf:value="#{bean.file}"/>
```

Is the adviced way

Comment: Hmmm thought that was the link I posted to…  now I see it was the wrong one.  Mea culpa

Comment: Just simple as that. Get it, thanks! But what about the backend? What do I store, the file path or there is a type for it?

Comment: please do a little searching in google or even in the 'related' column to the right here... And please accept the answer